# I can't find out why req.param('length') is returning 0

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, express, sails.js

I'm using Sails.js (which is based on Express), and I'm sending a `form input` named `length` which has a `value` of `'1000'`, like so:

```
<select name="length">
    <option value="1000">1000</option>
</select>
```

Server side, I have done some tests, and this is what I get

```
req.param('length');  // returns 0
req.params.length;    // returns 0
req.params.all()      // returns { length: '1000' }
```

I've also checked in the network tab of the developer's console, and I see the `POST` request being made, with a param of `length = "1000"`.

Either I'm missing something very obvious or this is a weird glitch.
**Why is this happening and how can I get the value of length instead of getting "0"?**

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to rename length by myLength ? Cause length is a key work maybe it's confusing for sails

Comment: Does `req.params['length']` work?

Comment: @jaumard Well, duh, that's why it's happening. Renaming `length` to `myLength` returns the actual value. I hadn't actually thought about renaming that! I have to remind myself of always using better words for my names. You can post your comment as an answer if you want. I think it might be useful in the remote chance someone finds themselves in this situation. Haha, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: You're welcome, just add it as an answer. Thanks ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just rename your select by `myLength`, because `length` is a JavaScript keyword, which is confusing for sails.

EDIT :

sorry `length` is not a keyword, but in javascript values/objects (like strings, arrays) can have a property `length` set by default.

Thanks to Felix Kling for the correction

Comment: `length` is not a keyword. If it was, I wouldn't be able to do `var length = 42;`. But even if it was a keyword, keywords are allowed as property names.

Comment: Maybe we can edit the answer to reflect that? (The fact that it is a property name, but it is set by 'default').

Comment: @JamHam: There are some values which have a "default" property `length`. Strings and arrays for example. In that case yes, you can't have your own `length` property. However, it's perfectly fine to have a "plain" object with a length property, e.g. `{length: 42}`.

Comment: And that's why `req.params.all()` returns the correct value of length as a property, I guess. Well, perhaps that would be editing the answer too much. And by looking at your comments people can get the right concept.

Comment: After looking into this all afternoon, it turns out all of the above comments are reasonable but ultimately incomplete: the reason this wasn't working correctly is due to the way the underlying Express server parses and stores route parameters.  It resulted in `req.param('length')` returning the number of _wildcard parameters_ (i.e. asterisks) in the route.  We're currently patching Sails to allow `length` to works as expected in the querystring or body (it'll never be a valid URL parameter, i.e. `/foo/:length` will never be an okay route).

Answer (score 1):

"length" is a word that you [should avoid when accessing objects](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp). So, you should not try to access "length" directly (ie. `obj.length`). You should probably change the underlying property name to something safe like `quantity` as mentioned by @jaumard:

```
<select name="quantity"></select>
```

Then you can access `req.params.quantity`.

Comment: `obj.length` and `ob['length']` are one and the same thing. There is no reason to avoid using `length`.

Comment: `length` is a property, right? I think he meant you shouldn't use `length` as a word because it might conflict with the JavaScript `length` property.

Comment: @JamHam: I can understand the `length` is better avoided in some situations to avoid conflicts. But this answer seems to suggest that there was a difference between `obj.length` and `obj['length']` and that's not the case. The former is just syntactic sugar for the latter.

Comment: @FelixKling "There is no reason to avoid using length", you really believe that? Also, accessing an object using a string **is** different than accessing it with dot notation. I went ahead and removed the part about `obj['length']`, but I think you are getting a little picky, my friend.

Comment: You are right. When working with third-party code, it may be better to avoid certain property names, because you may not know what kind of object are dealing with (although that would be easy to find out). There is no general reason to avoid `length` though. *"accessing an object using a string is different than accessing it with dot notation."* Care to elaborate on that? Of course bracket notation allows you to access properties that are not accessible with dot notation, but that doesn't apply to `length`. Is there any other difference you have in mind?

Comment: What I meant was that there is no difference between accessing a *specific property* (e.g. `length`) via dot or bracket notation. Of course there is a difference between dot notation and bracket notation in general.

Comment: Maybe I'm crazy, but I am really certain that accessing properties such as `myObj.class` is a bad thing to do. I don't recall the specifics. In other areas `myObj.person-1` would blow up and `myObj['person-1']` works fine. I was wrong about `length` being such a threat, but it is still bad practice to use common object property names. I still disagree with you that you should not avoid using "length" as a property and w3schools.com at least agrees with me. Lol. I guess it's just a matter of opinion.

Comment: `myObj.person-1` means "subtract 1 from `myObj.person`". `myObj['person-1']` means "access property with name 'person-1'". As said, there are situations where you have to use bracket notation. But if you can access a property with both, then both will yield the same result. Up to ES3 I believe it was disallowed to use (reserved) keywords as property names, so yes, `myObj.class` would be a syntax error. Since ES5 it is OK though. `length` is not a keyword, just a property that might exist, and as such should be treated like anything else that might exist by default.